# I'm getting "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command" error since I deleted anaconda files

Tags: python

I have been using python for about 1 year. I deleted the anaconda files on my computer and now I get this error. I thought they were unnecessary. Is Anaconda not an ide? Why is it no longer working because I deleted it? What should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anaconda is not an IDE, it's an open source distribution of Python and R. You should or reinstall anaconda and install again all python packages, or download python from the [webpage](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and just install python without anaconda.